# Error : Multiple definition of eventFilter in Qt

Tags: qt, qt5, eventfilter

I have 2 classes
**myView** and **myBrowser**

In *myView.cpp* I have already installed eventFilter which is working fine.

Now for 2nd class, *myBrowser.cpp* I want to install another eventFilter.
So I tried to install it but got following error.

> multiple definition of myView::eventFilter(QObject*,QEvent*)
> First defiend here :  ( path of myBrowser.cpp file )

myView.h

```
class myView :: public QDockWidget {

bool eventFilter(QObject* watched, QEvent* event);
}
```

myBrowser.h

```
class myBrowser :: public QDockWidget {

bool eventFilter(QObject* watched, QEvent* event);
}
```

How to install 2 eventFilter in 2 different classes ?

Comment: My crystal ball says you've copied the implementation code of `myView::eventFilter` from `myView.cpp` to `myBrowser.cpp` but forgot to edit the class name: i.e change `myView` to myBrowser`.  If that's not the case then please show the relevant code -- preferably in the form of a [mcve].